# Detect stack overflow with old GLIBC version

Tags: c++, linux, embedded

We suspect that we are encountering a stack overflow in our multithreaded program. However, as it is an embedded application, we have been unable to get valgrind etc working for it. Also, we are constrained to using GCC version v4.0.0 and GLIBC v2.3.2, which do not support the flag `-fstack-protector-all`.

How could we go about detecting whether the segmentation faults we are seeing are the result of a stack overflow in this instance? We have doubled the stack size of all our threads, and this fixes the problem, but we would like to be sure that this is a genuine fix.

Comment: Have you debugged those parts of the code to find excessive stack usage? Increasing the stack size may be a perfectly fine solution, but there may also be a subtle bug that is causing the issue.

Comment: Why are you constrained to GCC v4.0.0? Newer versions are backwards-compatible with objects and libraries built by previous versions, but even if you're forced to use that old version for some reason you could still install a newer version and use it just to find this problem, then go back to living in the past with your old compiler. 4.0.0 was the first ever releases following a major rewrite of the GCC code, surely you could at least use 4.0.4?

Comment: @JonathanWakely: Likely, the compiler is provided by the vendor that provided the embedded chip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can figure this out for yourself with a bit of care. If you set up your program to use a stack you allocated you can add a "guard page" to catch reads and writes to the first page past the end of the given stack. You can then install a signal handler to catch the signal and tell you if the segfault was caused by an access within that guard page.

This is the smallest example I could make that shows how to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ucontext.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <signal.h>

static char *guard = NULL;
static const int pagesize = getpagesize();

static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *info, void *ctx) {
  if ((char*)info->si_addr >= guard && (char*)info->si_addr - guard <= pagesize) {
    write(2, "stack overflow\n", 15);
  }
  write(2, "sigsegv caught\n", 15);
  _exit(-1);
}

static void install_handler() {
  // register sigsegv handler:
  static struct sigaction act;

  act.sa_sigaction = handler;
  sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
  act.sa_flags=SA_SIGINFO|SA_ONSTACK;

  // give the signal handler an alternative stack
  static char stack[4096];
  stack_t ss;
  ss.ss_size = sizeof(stack);
  ss.ss_sp = stack;
  if (sigaltstack(&ss, 0)) {
    perror("sigaltstack");
    fprintf(stderr,"failed to set sigstack\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  if (sigaction(SIGSEGV, &act, NULL)) {
    perror("sigaction");
    fprintf(stderr,"failed to set handler\n");
    exit(-1);
  }
}

static int overflow() {
  return overflow() + 1;
}

static void test()
{
    install_handler();
    puts("start test");
    // real code that might overflow
    // test non-overflow segv
    //*(char*)0 = 0;
    // test overflow
    overflow();
    puts("finish test");
}

int main()
{
    // create a stack and guard page:
    const int pagesize = getpagesize();
    char *st1=(char*)memalign(pagesize,1+(pagesize*4));
    guard = st1+(pagesize*4);
    if (mprotect(guard, pagesize, PROT_NONE)) {
      perror("mprotect");
      fprintf(stderr,"failed to protect guard page: %p \n", guard);
      return -1;
    }

    ucontext_t ctx[2];
    getcontext(&ctx[1]);
    ctx[1].uc_stack.ss_sp = st1;
    ctx[1].uc_stack.ss_size = 4*pagesize;
    ctx[1].uc_link = &ctx[0];
    makecontext(&ctx[1], test, 0);

    swapcontext(&ctx[0], &ctx[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

As well as using your own stack for your code to run in you have to supply another stack for the signal to be delivered using, otherwise the signal delivery itself will fail because of the guard page.

Comment: Thanks, there's lots of great ideas in there that have been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Do you get a corefile? You should be able to examine a stack trace (either by running the code in GDB or from a corefile) and see if there's a very deep call stack at the time of the crash